# Way to find all domains that have a CNAME to my domain?

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record, reverse-dns

I have a web service that allows users to white-label our software by using their own domain over ours. This is done by the user adding a CNAME record from their domain to our domain.

Is there a way to discover all of the domains that have a CNAME record configured to point to our domain?

I'm looking specifically for a command line tool similar to "host" (`$ host <domain>`) which looks up which IP addresses host that domain. If this doesn't exist, is there some other solution to finding this info?

Comment: No, this is obviously impossible.

Comment: Why the downvotes? It's not obviously impossible unless you have a solid grasp of how DNS is implemented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to discover all of the domains that have a CNAME record
>   configured to point to our domain?

No.

The best you can possibly do is start logging `Host:` headers or ensure that you're logging full request hostnames. Over time, you'll have built up a mostly-authoritative list of domains.

Comment: Thank you. Adding an alternative solution is very helpful! This should cover my needs.